# Pandas read_table using wrong column as index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I'm trying to make a dataframe for a url that is delimited by tabs. However, pandas is using the industry_code column as the index.

```
dff = pd.read_table('http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ce/ce.industry')
```

will output

```
    industry_code   naics_code  publishing_status   industry_name   display_level   selectable  sort_sequence
0    -   B   Total nonfarm   0   T   1  NaN
5000000  -   A   Total private   1   T   2  NaN
6000000  -   A   Goods-producing     1   T   3  NaN
7000000  -   B   Service-providing   1   T   4  NaN
8000000  -   A   Private service-providing   1   T   5  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy!

```
table_location = 'http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ce/ce.industry'
dff = pd.read_table(table_location, index_col=False)
```